# Does Ubuntu delete cache-thumbnails after leaving the guest mode?

Tags: cache, guest-session

When i leave the guestmode, are there still some cache files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a guest session a temporary user with a new `$HOME` folder is created. After leaving the guest session the user and its `$HOME` including the thumbnail cache and other cache files are removed.